# .htaccess file not redirecting scripts and styles when they are called within a script file

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, vue.js

While trying to create a hybrid nodejs app I came across the need to redirect all file requests to localhost:8080 during development. After some work with .htaccess I came up with this code that seems to work for files called in the header or footer of the page, but when a script calls a file the rules are not applied.

Here is the .htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(wp-)/*
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|css|js|ttf|woff|woff2|otf)$ http://localhost:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance that can be given!

Comment: Well, redirection works on incoming requests from clients, so typically browsers. It does _not_ work if the server itself is the client, since those requests are not served by the server itself in that case which is why the rewriting rules never get applied...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use environmental variables to use different url base in development vs production

here is a description on env variables from vue docs

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

essentially, you setup two files, `.env` and `.env.production` for production

in your `.env`

```
BASE_URL=http://localhost:8080/
```

and in `env.production`

```
NODE_ENV=production
BASE_URL=//
```

then in your code use something like

```js
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${process.env.BASE_URL}some-api/`,
  // baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL + 'some-api/',
});
```

Then, when you're building for production, use 
`vue-cli-service build --mode production`

otherwise, you can run the usual way to get the dev environment.

These values get parsed into the build, so in your production build, you won't see any `localhost:8080` in the source code.

Comment: Thanks for that insight, I am trying to merge a vuejs template and WordPress. Everything works after a build but I was hoping to avoid building each time I wanted to test changes.

Comment: The issue here seems to be that vuejs uses the url of the browser window instead of the dev environment url specified during serve

Comment: Aha, got it (I think). You could make all requests from Vue use absolute paths instead of relative. You can then use `process.env.ROOT` to toggle between `//` in production and `http://localhost:8080` during dev